# how to write R error to file

Tags: r

how can i write log to file in R the error in log how can i capture it?

Comment: Use `write` intead of `cat` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `file` argument to cat: just replace your last line with:

```
,error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n", file="yourfile.log")})
```

If you don't handle erros explicitly but want to keep a whole log of the run of your script you can use the `sink` function.